# SQL Server 2008 :: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have [ReconcileUserInformationComputed] trigger on Userinformation table

Userinformation table has below rows 
    [ID] ,[CompanyID] ,[Status] ,[FirstName] ,[LastName]

UserinformationComputed table has below rows 
    [id] ,[CompanyID] ,[law_id] ,[Status] ,[FirstName] ,[LastName]

Below is my trigger

```
USE [einvoice]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[ReconcileUserInformationComputed]    Script Date:    08/27/2014 10:53:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReconcileUserInformationComputed] ON [dbo].[UserInformation] AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- exit trigger when zero records affected
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            --UPDATE
                UPDATE [dbo].[UserInformationComputed]
                SET -- use new values from inserted 
                CompanyID = (SELECT CompanyID from inserted),
                law_id = (SELECT ID FROM inserted),
                Status = (SELECT Status FROM inserted),
                FirstName = (SELECT FirstName FROM inserted),
                LastName = (SELECT LastName FROM inserted),
    WHERE  -- use original values from deleted
                law_id = (SELECT ID FROM deleted)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --INSERT
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserInformationComputed] (CompanyID,law_id,Status,FirstName,LastName)
     SELECT CompanyID,id,Status,FirstName,LastName) FROM inserted
   END
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    --DELETE
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[UserInformationComputed]
    WHERE law_id = (SELECT id FROM deleted)
END
```

when try to update multiple users on Userinformation am getting 
below error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReconcileUserInformationComputed, Line 16
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I made the changes as per the answer it worked for the above trigger but same changes didnt work for another trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReconcileCrossRefComputed] ON [dbo].[CrossRef] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- exit trigger when zero records affected
    BEGIN
       RETURN
    END
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            --UPDATE
            UPDATE [dbo].[CrossRefComputed]
            SET -- use new values from inserted 
            SenderId = inserted.SenderId,
            ReceiverId = inserted.ReceiverId,
            ForeignRef = inserted.ForeignRef,
            PolicyID = inserted.PolicyID,
        From inserted
        WHERE -- use original values from deleted
        [CrossRefComputed].SenderId = inserted.SenderId
        AND [CrossRefComputed].ReceiverId = inserted.ReceiverId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --INSERT
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CrossRefComputed] (SenderId, ReceiverId, ForeignRef, PolicyID)
        SELECT SenderId, ReceiverId, Effective, PolicyID FROM inserted
    END
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    --DELETE
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[CrossRefComputed]
    WHERE SenderId in (SELECT SenderId FROM deleted)
    AND ReceiverId in (SELECT ReceiverId FROM deleted)
END
```

COuld anyone please help me how to fix the procedure to handle updating multiple records?

Comment: don't use `=` for a multi-result subquery. use `IN` (...)` instead.

Comment: like CompanyID in (SELECT CompanyID from inserted) ?

Comment: You are so close... 1 value = 1 value or 1 value in (list of values)...never 1 value = list of values

Comment: Is it CompanyID in (SELECT * from inserted)? am a very beginner to sql stuff so please don't get me wrong if this one is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that an UPDATE or a DELETE can affect more than one record and your trigger will have to deal with them at once, in this case your "inserted" or "deleted" table will have more than one record.

You will have to use a join in your DML. Something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[UserInformationComputed]
                SET
                CompanyID = inserted.CompanyID,
                law_id = inserted.ID,
                Status = inserted.Status,
                FirstName = inserted.FirstName,
                LastName = inserted.LastName
            from inserted
    WHERE  
                UserInformationComputed.law_id = inserted.ID
```

I haven't perfectly understood your UPDATE logic, so you'll have to adapt my code.

In your DELETE command you may have just to change "=" to "in":

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[UserInformationComputed]
    WHERE law_id in (SELECT id FROM deleted)
```

Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx

Comment: #Caffe I made the changes as u suggested to UserInformationComputed trigger it worked but its not working for the triiger ReconcileCrossRefComputed(updated in my answer)

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @RanPaul I cant' see any subquery in your ReconcileCrossRefComputed procedure, so it's a very strange error. The complete error message tells the trigger name and the line number, right? Is really "ReconcileCrossRefComputed" the one who is throwing the error? In which line?

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReconcileCrossRefComputed, Line 13 (which is UPDATE [dbo].[CrossRefComputed])

Comment: @RanPaul Oh man! I'm upset. It doesn't make sense to me; there's no subquery in this trigger. Are you sure you are really executing this code you pasted in your question?

Comment: Yes I am executing the same code pasted in my question

Comment: @RanPaul Maybe another trigger in table CrossRefComputed causing the error?

Comment: We have only one trigger on the table

Comment: I mean, you've shown a trigger of CrossRef which updates CrossRefComputed. Would this last one have its own trigger? If so, would be that one who is throwing the error?

Comment: Nope there are no triggers on CrossRefComputed, we have only 1 trigger on Crossref which updates CrossRefComputed